# Logging in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I can see there are a couple of parameters to configure logging in Odoo. But I'm not sure what is the difference. They are:

```
log_level
log_handler
```

What are they used for? What is the diference between:

```
log_level = info
log_handler= :INFO
```

In some references I understand log_handler OVERRIDES log_level, but in some other I undertand the refer to different things. If I set:

```
log_level=error
log_handler=:INFO
```

Log is registered only for error and superior levels, and log_handler has no effect.

Also, I see in some sources, they refer to

```
logger_<module_name>
```

to get granurality in levels. For example:

```
logger_my_module = error
```

Is this correct? What is it used for and works together with the other parameters?

Thanks! :)